# How to create a factory to create derived object accepting arguments of more derived type

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, factory

I have a problem with designing a proper solution for a factory for a family of common-based classes. I have a class called Verifier, the class will have only method Verify which accepts instance of Specification as a parameter

```
public abstract class Verifier 
{
    public virtual bool Verify(Specification spec) 
    {
        //does the common job
        return true; //or false
    }
}
```

Then I have a set of concrete Verifiers

```
public abstract class FirstVerifier : Verifier
{
    public override bool Verify(Specification spec) 
    {
       //does the job, maybe even calls for base or maybe not
       return true; 
    }
}

public abstract class SecondVerifier : Verifier
{
    public override bool Verify(Specification spec) 
    {
       //does the job, maybe even calls for base or maybe not
       return true; 
    }
}
```

Then I have a nice factory which returns me a proper instance:

```
public class VerifierFactory 
{
    public static Verifier Create(string type) //not actually a string, but does not matter
    {
        switch (type) 
        {
            case "First": return new FirstVerifier();
            case "Second": return new SecondVerifier();
            default: throw new Exception();
        } 
    }
}
```

Now I have a requirement that the Verifiers can Verify not the instances of Specification but derived types of Specification, like:

```
public abstract class FirstVerifier : Verifier
{
    public override bool Verify(SpecificationOne spec)  //SpecificationOne derives from Specification
    {
       //does the job, maybe even calls for base or maybe not
       return true; 
    }
}

public abstract class SecondVerifier : Verifier
{
    public override bool Verify(SpecificationTwo spec) //SpecificationOne derives from Specification
    {
       //does the job, maybe even calls for base or maybe not
       return true; 
    }
}
```

This obviously will not compile, and I don't want to do tricks like this:

```
public abstract class FirstVerifier : Verifier
{
    public override bool Verify(Specification spec)
    {
       var realSpecification = spec as SpecificationOne;
       if(realSpecification == null)
          throw new Exception();
       // do job
    }
}
```

I am thinking of a solution (maybe a generic one) in which my factory returns proper type which in turn accepts proper type in Verify method, so that then I can use my factory to create verifiers and call verify, like this:

```
specifications.Select(s => VerifierFactory.Create(typeof(s)).Verify(s))
```

Comment: There are good reasons that the language does not allow what you are trying to do. See duplicate. Depending on your specific situation, there are alternatives that could work, but you need to research those alternatives, determine which if any are in fact suitable, make an attempt to apply them, and post a question only if you have some _specific_ difficulty you need help with.

Comment: The linked question does not answer my question because I explicitly said I don't want to check if argument is a specific subtype of the class. The linked question does not even mention the factory problems which is the main difficulty I wanted to solve.

Comment: The factory aspect of your question doesn't affect the answer at all. It's an unnecessary distraction. As far as whether you want to check the argument type or not, that's fine, but it also doesn't change what's legal in the language or not. The duplicate is the direct answer to the only non-open-ended question in your post. The open-ended part of your question is not appropriate or suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use generic method. For example:

```
public abstract class Verifier 
{
    public virtual bool Verify<T>(T  spec) where T: Specification
    {
        //does the common job
        return true; //or false
    }
}
```

Or you can use generic class, for example:

Create the base `Specification` class

```
public class Specification
{
    //some properties, fields and etc
}
```

And inherit your other specification from the base `Specification` class

```
public class SpecificationOne : Specification
{
    //some properties, fields and etc
}


public class SpecificationTwo : Specification
{
    //some properties
}
```

After create the base `Verifier` class, that it is generic class.

```
public abstract class Verifier<T> where T : Specification
{
    public virtual bool Verify(T spec)
    {
        //does the common job
        return true; //or false
    }
}
```

And inherit your other verifier classes from base `Verifier<T>` class. **These classes must be not abstract, because we will create instance in `VerifierFactory`**. For example:

```
public class FirstVerifier : Verifier<SpecificationOne>
{
    public override bool Verify(SpecificationOne spec)
    {
        var baseResult = base.Verify(spec);

        //some logic

        return baseResult;
    }
}

public class SecondVerifier : Verifier<SpecificationTwo>
{
    public override bool Verify(SpecificationTwo spec)
    {
        var baseResult = base.Verify(spec);

        //some logic

        return baseResult;
    }
}
```

And you can create `VerifierFactory` like as below:

```
public class VerifierFactory
{
    public static Verifier<T> Create<T>(T spec) where T : Specification
    {
        if (spec.GetType() == typeof(SpecificationOne))
            return new FirstVerifier() as Verifier<T>;

        if (spec.GetType() == typeof(SpecificationTwo))
            return new SecondVerifier() as Verifier<T>;

        //and etc...
        // I think you project must have one default Verifier class for else case
    }
}
```

Finally you can use linq query like as below:

```
specifications.Select(s => VerifierFactory.Create(s).Verify(s))
```

Comment: Why not change the parameter type to `T`, and add `where T : Specification`?

Comment: @gunr2171 you are right, I will edit my answer

Comment: Actually, another option is to move the definition of `<T>` to the class rather than the method.

Comment: @gunr2171 Do make Verifier class to generic?

Comment: The OP could, it's a possible option, though it's a design decision to do `public abstract class Verifier<T> where T : Specification`. That way could you have a `public class FirstVerifier : Verifier<SpecificationOne>`, and the generic parameter threads through to the Verify method.

Comment: @gunr2171 I took into account what you said in my answer.

Comment: Ok, but how the VerifierFactory.Create example implementation should look like?

Comment: @vanpersil I added VerifierFactory example to my answer

Comment: This solution assumes that the source list contains all specifications of the same type. If that's fine, this will work, otherwise you're limited to the single type in the source list.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this solution. Start with a base verifier that is generic and provides a default implementation that verifies the `Specification` part and then calls into subclasses' implementations to verify the `T` part.

```
public abstract class Verifier<T> where T : Specification 
{
    // in most cases you probably wouldn't override this
    // in subclasses, but you could if necessary
    public virtual bool Verify(Specification spec) 
    {
        if (!VerifyCommon(spec)) return false;
        return VerifyImplementation((T)spec);
    }

    protected abstract bool VerifyImplementation(T spec);

    protected bool VerifyCommon(Specification spec)
    {
        //does the common job
        return true; //or false
    }
}
```

Your factory doesn't really have to change at all. Your subclasses would implement the abstract `VerfifyImplementation` in each case.

```
public class FirstVerifier : Verifier<SpecificationOne>
{
    protected override bool VerifyImplementation(SpecificationOne spec)
    {
       // do job
       return ...;
    }
}
```

Your `select` will have to change to something like

```
specifications.Select(s => VerifierFactory.Create(s.GetType()).Verify(s))
```

This solution has the advantage of applying the same validation pattern in each case and avoids casting in the subclasses (though you do have a cast in the base class).

This solution, however, has a disadvantage in that `FirstVerifier` could accept the wrong subclass of `Specification` in `Verify(Specification)`. To fix this, you can change the base verifier to

```
public abstract class Verifier<T> where T : Specification 
{
    public virtual bool Verify(T spec) 
    {
        if (!VerifyCommon(spec)) return false;
        return VerifyImplementation(spec);
    }

    protected abstract bool VerifyImplementation(T spec);

    protected bool VerifyCommon(Specification spec)
    {
        //does the common job
        return true; //or false
    }
}
```

But this means your `select` will have to do some dynamic magic to ensure the `Verify` method can be called correctly:

```
specifications.Select(s => VerifierFactory.Create(s.GetType()).Verify((dynamic)s))
```

This implementation eliminates the cast inside `Verify` and ensures type safety, but at the (likely negligible) cost of invoking the `Verify` method dynamically.

The nice thing about both implementations is they

- avoid calling a `base.Verify()` , which is sometimes a source of bugs when developers of the subclasses forget to call that `base.Verify()`.
- can operate on a heterogeneous list of `Specification`.